# help to understand this for loop code

Tags: java, for-loop

I can not understand how this code draws a complete chess board not only 8 squares

Especially : How  `for-loop`  it works.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class chbord extends GraphicsProgram {
    /* number of columns */
    private static final int Ncolumns = 8;
    /* number of rows*/
    private static final int Nrows = 8;

    public void run() {
        int sqSize = getHeight() / Nrows;
        for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Ncolumns; j++) {
                int x = j * sqSize;
                int y = i * sqSize;

                GRect sq = new GRect(x, y, sqSize, sqSize);
                sq.setFilled(((i + j) % 2) != 0);
                add(sq);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Ncolumns * Nrows = 64 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the outer loop runs, the inner loop runs completely (8 times). Then the outer loop runs a second time and the inner loop is then run completely once again (another 8 times).

This continues through the eighth row.

So you get 8 rows drawn, but each row is drawn as 8 columns.

Result: all 64 squares are drawn.

**Especially : How for-loop it works.**

A For-loop is a key part of programming. Here are some explanation articles:

- [An article explaining javascript](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptfor.php) loops. -- The syntax may be a bit different but the idea is the same.
- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)

Answer (score 2):

There's a loop within a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Ncolumns; j++)
```

Each loop has 8 iterations:

```
/* number of columns */
private static final int Ncolumns = 8;
/* number of rows*/
private static final int Nrows = 8;
```

That makes 64 total iterations (8 x 8) through the inner loop - one for each chess square.

Answer (score 1):

While both the posters above are correct consider that the second loop runs 8 times for each one time the first loop runs. To demonstrate put two different System.out.println statements in each loop and view the order that they are printed in.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are actually two for loops, not just one. This is called "nesting" loops, and it's the typical approach used to create row x column grids such as a chessboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a nested loop - one loop inside another. The outer loop causes the code it contains to be executed for values of i between 0 and nrows - 1, inclusive. The inner loop causes the code it contains to be executed for values of j between 0 and ncols - 1, inclusive. Since the code in the inner loop is executed for n values of i, and for each of these values of i, m values of j, the total number of executions is nm.

Answer (score 0):

the outer and inner loop will create an NRows*NColumns grid and the modulus operator (%) will color every other square since there are only two values with MOD 2.